# PostgreSQL reverse of PERCENTILE_CONT

Tags: postgresql

I want to do the opposite of PERCENTILE_CONT does; instead of asking to return the value at a given percentile, I want to supply the value and get its percentile within a column back. For example, if we consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (this_list INT)
INSERT INTO tbl (this_list) VALUES (60, 40, 80, 20)

| this_list |
| --------- |
| 60        |
| 40        |
| 80        |
| 20        |

SELECT
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY this_list)
FROM
    this_list
```

I end up with 65. I want a function to specify 65 and get back 0.75. I already checked PERCENT_RANK(), but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to use it? Please show us your attempt.